# Incron commands with arguments

Tags: scripting, incron

I know cron can execute commands with arguments and the documentation implies that incron can as well, but it doesn't give examples. I tried using incron with arguments like this

```
/home/alex/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/cttools.sty  IN_MODIFY,IN_CREATE /bin/bash   /home/alex/bashscripts/luatoxe /home/alex/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/cttools.sty
```

and in a few variations but it doesn't seem to work at all. So how do I specify arguments for incron right? For completeness, `luatoxe` is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
cp $1 x$1
sed -i "/setmainfont/"' s/^/%/' "x$1"
sed -i "/setmathfont/"' s/^/%/' "x$1"
```

I also made a variant `luatoxect` where I specify the file path to `cttools` in the file itself, which works if I use it with incron.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used incrond but when I did, it had some idiosyncracies.

In the version I was using, the parameters in the config file are NOT seperated by blank/non-blank transitions (like shell arguments or crontabs) but by *a single space*. You appear to have multiple spaces here.

(I also found the recurive detection seemed to behave inconsistently)

Comment: Thanks but I'm pretty sure those spaces were added by the program in formatting. In any case, all the other entries work, and those have the same format, just no arguments at the end.